# Java, Dropbox V2 : Get only names and paths of folders, not files.

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

Dropbox sdk version : 3.0.3

Hello friends,

I am working on migrating dropbox to v2. Other tasks like upload, download, delete are complete, but we are having some issues with folder-names and path. I would like to get a list of folders only from Dropbox, so user can upload files to the desired folder. Whenever I try the below code, I get files as well, and the method is listFolders.

How can I get folders only with V2 API? Thank you.

Code :

```
      DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, person.getDropboxAccessToken());
            ListFolderResult listing = client.files().listFolderBuilder("").start();
  for (Metadata child : listing.getEntries()) {
                stringList.put(child.getPathDisplay(),child.getPathDisplay());
            }
```

This stringList is just for testing, but in entries, I cannot get folders. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, the method [`files().listFolderBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderBuilder-java.lang.String-) (i.e., not `listFoldersBuilder`) is a way to list all of the contents inside a particular folder. In your code, you're supplying the `""` path, which identifies the root folder.

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to list folders only, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

That being the case, if you want to list folders only (and not files) you'll need to check the type of the returned entries. You can do so using `instanceof`, e.g., as [shown here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/7ecc15cf0f51d6ae2ba5cdb334aac2c2f3474b87/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/FilesAdapter.java#L82), to check if the entry is a `FolderMetadata`, `FileMetadata`, or `DeletedMetadata`.

Comment: @Greg : Is this support available now? ie' to get folder list alone and api to get folders count..

Comment: @rm-rf No, the Dropbox API still does not offer this functionality.